# Count each character

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to count each `char` in string for example:

Sample input: `abababx`

Sample output :

```
a appears 3 times
b appears 3 times
x appears 1 time
```

Here is what I've done :

```
 String s = input.nextLine();

    //Invoke the count method to count each letter
    int[] counts = countLetters(s.toLowerCase());

    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
        if (counts[i] != 0)
            System.out.println((char)('a' - i) + " appears " +
            counts[i] + ((counts[i] == 1 ? " time" : " times")));
    }


private static int[] countLetters(String s) {
    int[] counts = new int[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)))
            counts[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
    }

    return counts;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
 a appears 3 times
` appears 3 times
J appears 1 time
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Change `'a' - i` to `'a' + i`

Comment: Oh good catch thanks @shmosel

Comment: `'a' - i` should be `'a' + i` instead. `i` is the offset starting from `'a'`

Comment: Voting to close as a typographical/trivial error